# How to perform a redirect in Enlight_Event_EventArgs object subscriber in Shopware 5?

Tags: shopware

I have a subscriber to the event

```
'Shopware_Modules_Admin_SaveRegister_Successful'
```

and after certain actions, I want to perform a redirect in the end, but the `$args` object does not have a subject which means that I cannot call the `$controller = $args->getSubject();` on it and perform a redirect.

Is there another way to perform a redirect inside of the callback function of this event? `'Shopware_Modules_Admin_SaveRegister_Successful' => 'onRegisterSuccessful'`

```
public function onRegisterSuccessful($args){
         $controller = $args->getSubject();
         $controller->redirect(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'profile',
                    'action' => 'verify',
                    'name' => $name
                )
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. Note that you need to exit() after the redirect, because after the event is fired, Shopware makes its own redirect to the customer dashboard.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Shopware_Modules_Admin_SaveRegister_Successful' => 'onregister'
    ];
}

public function onRegister(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    $url = Shopware()->Front()->Router()->assemble([
            'controller' => 'profile',
            'action' => 'verify'
    ]);

    header('Location: ' . $url, true);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your option would be to go a bit higher and register an controller's `postDispatch` event. There you can redirect.

Comment: I know about that, but is there a possibility to do a redirect right from there?